# How to make a better coding of this code

Tags: exception, null

I have the following code :

```
string name1;
string name2;
string name3;

try
{
    name1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name1']").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
    name2 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name2']").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
    name3 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name3']").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
}
catch(Exception)
{
    name1 = "";
    name2 = "";
    name3 = "";
}
```

Even thought I couldnt find a case, there is a chance the node is not found and the function SelectSingleNode() returns null.
But if one of them gives an error, all 3 string would be empty.I could solve it like the code below but I dont like calling 3 try/catch in a row like this, is there a better way to do this?

```
try
{
    name1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name1']").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
} catch (Exception)
{
    name1 = "";
}

try
{
    name2 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name2']").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
} catch (Exception)
{
    name2 = "";
}

try
{
    name3 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name3']").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
} catch (Exception)
{
    name3 = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the following solution may help you.

```
        try {
        if (null != htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name1']") && null != htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name1']").GetAttributeValue("value", "")) {
            name1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name1']").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
        } else {
            name1 = null;
        }

        if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name2']") && null != htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name2']").GetAttributeValue("value", "")) {
            name2 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name2']").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
        } else {
            name2 = null;
        }

        if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name3']") && null != htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name3']").GetAttributeValue("value", "")) {
            name3 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='name3']").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
        } else {
            name3 = null;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```